# Setting Message Payload to Session Variable

Tags: mule

In my Mule flow, I have a message that is constantly being edited to form a record of all processing at the end of the flow. At one point, I make an HTTP call to a webservice to get some details for the message.

My problem is the following:
The HTTP response is saved as the message payload which requires me to save my master record to a session variable in order to save all previous processing. However, when I set the session variable, the value of the session variable is java.class@d6883 (java.class = the class of the object. Had to edit to comply with my code of conduct). How do I set the value of the message payload into a session variable rather than the memory location of the message payload?

Comment: could you share how you are currently setting the session variable?

Comment: <set-session-variable variableName="tempCanonical" value="#[message:payload]" doc:name="Set tempCanonical"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the object you put in session is `Serializable`, you can achieve this using MEL:

```
<set-session-variable variableName="tempCanonical" value="#[message.payload]" />
```

Comment: That's the initial value that I used and came out with the java.class@d6883 output. It wasn't until later that I tried #[message:payload]

Comment: I don't get it: this *is* the way for storing the message payload in a session variable. Now maybe the payload don't have a `toString()` method implemented hence the default rendering of "java.class@d6883" when you output it *as string*. But the object should be there in the session.

Comment: Is there a way to refer to tempCanonical using the ${} notation? ${session.tempCanonical} didn't give me access to the values.

Comment: No `${}` is for configuration properties. You need to use MEL, i.e. either `#[tempCanonical]` or if you fear the value may be missing `#[flowVars['tempCanonical']]`